# Postgres 9 \COPY FROM Command - Reserved Keyword

Tags: postgresql, copy

I am having an issue trying to run \copy command where my column name is **desc**

I've tried the following:

```
psql -U user -p 1234 -h hostname -c "\copy schema.table (desc) from /my/file.txt WITH DELIMITER '|' HEADER CSV " db
psql -U user -p 1234 -h hostname -c "\copy schema.table ('desc') from /my/file.txt WITH DELIMITER '|' HEADER CSV " db
psql -U user -p 1234 -h hostname -c "\copy schema.table ("desc") from /my/file.txt WITH DELIMITER '|' HEADER CSV  db
```

I get the same error everytime:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "desc"
```

I can't seem to get around it. Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just escape double quotes, like here:

```
vao@vao-X102BA:~$ psql -c "copy s1(\"desc\") from stdin;"
Enter data to be copied followed by a newline.
End with a backslash and a period on a line by itself.
>> b
>> \.
COPY 1
vao@vao-X102BA:~$ psql
psql (9.6.3)
Type "help" for help.

vao=# select * from s1;
 i | desc
---+------
   | a
   | b

(2 rows)
```